# Dependence between conditionalPanels shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to select a value inside a list in the app below, in the panel I can see different elements when I select a list, but the output of double selection does not work

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
sampList <- list(1:3, 1:4, 1:6) 

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel('Choose methods to compare'),
sidebarPanel(
         wellPanel(
        selectInput(
          "method1", "Method 1",
        c(Method1 = "method1",
          Method2 = "method2",
          Method3 = "method3"
          )),

        conditionalPanel(
           condition = "input.method1 == 'method1'",
                 selectInput(
                  "member1", "Member",
                  sampList[[1]] )

              ),
     conditionalPanel(
           condition = "input.method1 == 'method2'",
                 selectInput(
                  "member1", "Member",
                  sampList[[2]] )
           ),

          conditionalPanel(
           condition = "input.method1 == 'method3'",
                 selectInput(
                  "member1", "Member",
                  sampList[[3]] )

              )    ),
    mainPanel(
       textOutput('table')

            )
)
)
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


    output$table <- renderText({

    c(input$method1, input$member1)
  })




})
```

In this example, when I select "Method 1" I see the correct vector (1:3) and if I select a number I see the correct output (the output is printed if one runs the app), but If I choose the other "Methods" the selection inside the vector is not printed, any guess?

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered by Stéphane Laurent in 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shiny-discuss.

You could call them `method1_member, method2_member,` ...
And then you get it by doing `input[[paste0(input$method1, "_member")]]`